# Freeware to remove visible hyperlinks from PDF documents

Tags: gratis, pdf, hyperlink

I received a digital copy of an old script written by one of my earlier professors and I'd like to print it. Unfortunately, the PDF document uses LaTeX hyperlinks with the [classic red border](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126089/red-boxes-around-hyperlinks) and the print service does not appear to automatically hide them.

Is there any gratis tool to remove visible hyperlinks from PDF documents? I do not have access to the LaTeX sources, only to the final PDF document.

Comment: Not that I know any, but: What OS should it run on?